# php best way to retrieve multiple xml file performance caching

Tags: php, xml, json, performance, caching

I'm a bit confused on how to this in a performance optic.

I will try to describe as much possible the process of my page.

First of all my page is showing content that users of my website are posting. New content is added every seconds, but i only show like 20 or 50 content per page.

Now is where i need some help : 
For every content i show, i need to retrieve the online status of the user who posted that content. This online status **is not** the online status of the user on my website but **his online status in an online software.** To retrieve this status i can download a json file stored on the webserver of that software.

I said before i'm showing 20 content per page, so i would need to download 20 json file. Well no, i can concatenate the user_id when i'm calling the json file. So in 1 json file i can get the 20 status.
Anyway, i think for the performance of my server it is not good to download a json file everytime someone visit my page. Because this page can be visited by a lot of people at the same time.

I guess i have to do something with caching but i'm new into. It would be glad if someone could explain me how to implement this, i mean the process and maybe the main php function to use.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's wrong with the way you are caching the json now?

Comment: i'm not caching anything atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to implement this would be sort of a read through cache. Meaning you check first if the cache (probably memcached) has current data, otherwise you read through and do a request and then cache the result. With memcached you can set the data to expire (maybe 1-5 minutes) before your code will attempt to read it from the source again.

You will need to take into account network issues into how you implement this. You will need to make sure your request times out rather quickly, or users could be waiting for a long time for the page to load (if data is not coming from the cache)

A more robust solution, would allow the online status to be checked asynchronously. When the page is loaded, you would pull data from the cache, if its missing, you would trigger a job to get the status and update the cache. You would have ajax code on the client side which will update the online status after the page is loaded (and hopefully after the job completes in the background). Those statuses that are available when the page loads would show correctly, and those that are pending would show some sort of "checking" status.

Comment: Perfect that's what i was waiting for. Yes i will probably do everything by ajax so the rest can load without problem. Im going to look about memcached and thanks for explaining me the process. I was thinking on something like that but was not really sure. Also, with memcached can i store specific informations into it ? Best i think would be to store the user_id and online status. If it's not into cache, i download the json and cache it. Right ?

Comment: Memcached is a memory based key/value store. So you would store the online status with a key something like status_userid.